# Linking to translated internal content in TinyMCE wysiwyg

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, wysiwyg

What's the best way to allow editors to link to internal content using the TinyMCe wysiwyg editor in a way that provides the correct alias based on the end user language?  For example, I would like them to enter a link like `/blog/some-great-news` in the wysiwyg and have it return `/de/some-great-news` when the reader is viewing the German page.

It looks like CKEditor has [something like what I need](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_link) and I use Internationalization (i18n).